# Application exe has created using auto-pay-to-exe utility. This app exe is opening, but getting closed immediately

Tags: python

As mentioned in the the title, after thorough testing of .py program on Jupiter notebook, I have created app exe using auto-py-to-exe utility.
The program created is for TicTac game, it is programmed to run infinitely, until user close it(it  is working as expected while running the program from Jupiter notebook), but while running the exe (app), it opens and get closed immediately the App window Without taking user input.
Please suggest how to resolve this issue to keep the window open receiving user input.

Comment: Try opening it using a command window. It's most likely spitting out and error that you cant see since its closing so quickly.